# Calling cuda() with async results in SyntaxError

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run this PyTorch code:

```
for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):

    input = input.float().cuda(async=True)
    target = target.cuda(async=True)
    input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)
    target_var = torch.autograd.Variable(target)

    output = model(input_var)
```

But when I try I am getting this error message:

```
input = input.float().cuda(async=True)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I already installed cuda.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Your code does not work because:**

- `async` is a reserved keyword in python which cannot be used in that way, that is why you get the `SyntaxError`
- `cuda()` **no longer** has an argument `async`. The constructor looks like this:

> **cuda**(*device=None, non_blocking=False*) → Tensor

- Previously there was an argument `async` but this replaced by `non_blocking` as `async` became a reserved keyword in Python 3.7.

   https://github.com/pluskid/fitting-random-labels/pull/5

### Use instead `non_blocking`:

The argument `non_blocking` has the same effect as `async` previously had:

> - `non_blocking` *(bool):* 
>   If `True` and the source is in pinned memory, the
>   copy will be asynchronous with respect to the host. Otherwise, the
>   argument has no effect. Default: `False`.
>
>    https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda

---

*As an add-on: If you are interested in what `async` is actually used for you can take a look here:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-syntax*

Answer (score 10):

There was an `async` parameter but it was deprecated now, because `async` became a reserved word in Python 3.7. Details are included in this issue [rename .cuda(async=..) parameters](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3431). You can use `non_blocking` as an alternative.