# How to get index.cuda?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am reading a code about CMC downloaded from github, and it can't work on vscode.

Code:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
        index = index.cuda(async=True)
        inputs = inputs.cuda()
```

Error message is as follows:

```
  File "e:\CMC-master\train_CMC.py", line 219
    index = index.cuda(async=True)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix it?

Comment: what is your pytorch version? what cuda toolkit version?

Comment: pytorch: '1.7.0+cu110'      cuda toolkit: 11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `non_blocking=True` instead:

```py
index = index.cuda(non_blocking=True)
```

See [`Tensor.cuda`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda) for more information, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212781/1714410) answer.